# Error while integrating google_maps: 6.2.0 for flutter web

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-web

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')
    at http://localhost:63982/packages/tripdesk_agency_web/app/pages/location/maps.dart.lib.js:57:47
    at http://localhost:63982/dart_sdk.js:172648:63
    at IdentityMap.new.putIfAbsent (http://localhost:63982/dart_sdk.js:28154:21)
    at _engine.PlatformViewManager.new.renderContent (http://localhost:63982/dart_sdk.js:172627:44)
    at [_createPlatformView] (http://localhost:63982/dart_sdk.js:172765:43)
    at _engine.PlatformViewMessageHandler.new.handlePlatformViewCall (http://localhost:63982/dart_sdk.js:172781:38)
    at [_sendPlatformMessage] (http://localhost:63982/dart_sdk.js:172134:63)
    at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.sendPlatformMessage (http://localhost:63982/dart_sdk.js:171971:33)
    at _DefaultBinaryMessenger.send (http://localhost:63982/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:6127:38)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:63982/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1562:50)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:63982/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:63982/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at [_invokeMethod] (http://localhost:63982/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1560:20)
    at MethodChannel.invokeMethod (http://localhost:63982/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1573:33)
    at platform_view$._HtmlElementViewController.new._initialize (http://localhost:63982/packages/flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart.lib.js:517:61)
    at _initialize.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:63982/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:63982/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at [_initialize] (http://localhost:63982/packages/flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart.lib.js:515:20)
    at [_createHtmlElementView] (http://localhost:63982/packages/flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart.lib.js:466:30)
    at [_initialize] (http://localhost:63982/packages/flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart.lib.js:1108:118)
    at platform_view$._PlatformViewLinkState.new.initState (http://localhost:63982/packages/flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart.lib.js:1090:24)
    at [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:63982/packages/flutter/src/widgets/title.dart.lib.js:53943:54)




======== Exception caught by scheduler library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
Assertion failed: "Cannot render platform views: 0. These views have not been created, or they have been deleted."

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49  throw_
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/embedded_views.dart 555:9                        submitFrame
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/rasterizer.dart 36:33                            draw
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 586:7                             render
lib/ui/window.dart 104:50                                                     render
packages/flutter/src/rendering/view.dart 231:15                               compositeFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 508:18                            drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 892:13                              drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 370:5                             [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1146:15                           [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1083:9                            handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 997:5                             [_handleDrawFrame]
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1090:13                           invoke
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 160:5                             invokeOnDrawFrame
lib/_engine/engine/initialization.dart 194:45                                 <fn>
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this in the html file

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=LIBRARY1,LIBRARY2"></script>
```